# Understanding Bruhat's notion of Schwartz function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, schwartz-distributions

I am trying to understand Bruhat's  generalized Schwartz functions over (Hausforff) locally compact Abelian groups [[1]](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/BSMF/BSMF_1961__89_/BSMF_1961__89__43_0/BSMF_1961__89__43_0.pdf), following this paper [[2]](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0022123675900051/1-s2.0-0022123675900051-main.pdf?_tid=2200009c-778f-11e3-97b1-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1389094418_6b150abe81557e4cc4cad07ed41bedec) by Osborne. There, the  [Schwartz-Bruhat](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%25E2%2580%2593Bruhat_function&ei=lw7MUrqwMrC00QXNj4Ag&usg=AFQjCNEB4n0xqvuVYMRkOmbUJOe2WmTUUg&sig2=GGFur4wek_nyObDgx3krZw&bvm=bv.58187178,d.d2k) space $\mathscr{S}(G)$  of complex functions  over a (Hausdorff) locally compact Abelian group $G$ is defined based on the notion of differential operators on groups. I have trouble understanding how differential operators are defined in groups that are discrete; see questions 1 and 2 below.

For simplicity I only look at groups of the form
For simplicity (and as in the [previous post](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0022123675900051/1-s2.0-0022123675900051-main.pdf?_tid=2200009c-778f-11e3-97b1-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1389094418_6b150abe81557e4cc4cad07ed41bedec) ) I will always assume that $G$ is a group of the form
$$G=\mathbb{R}^a\times\mathbb{T}^b\times\mathbb{Z}^c\times F$$,
where $\mathbb{T}^m$ is an $m$-dimensional torus and  $F$ an finite Abelian group given in the form $$F=\mathbb{Z}_{d_1}\times\cdots\times \mathbb{Z}_{d_e}.$$

For groups of the form $G$, the space $\mathscr{S}(G)$ is defined as follows: a function $f$ is in $\mathscr{S}(G)$ if $f$ is infinitely differentiable, and  if $P(\partial)f\in L^2(G)$ for every polynomial (in the $\mathbb{R}^a\times \mathbb{Z}^c$ variables) differential operator $P(\partial)$ on $G$.

> **Question 1** What is a ``polynomial differential operator $P(\partial)$'' over a group $G$? I am vaguely aware that groups of the form $G$ are the abelian Lie groups that are compactly-generated (cf. [[3]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3037190167)). Therefore, I assume there must exist a robust-notion of differentiability of functions over these groups. Still I do not know how differential operators on function spaces over discrete groups such as $\mathbb{Z}^c$ or $F$ should be defined.
>
> **Question 2** Why does $P(\partial)$ have to be a polynomial differential operator *only* in the $\mathbb{R}^a\times \mathbb{Z}^c$ variables. I do not understand why $\mathbb{T}^b$ and $F$ are not mentioned. Does it perhaps something to do with compactness?

**Related posts.**

I have opened another [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153856/characterizing-the-schwartz-bruhat-space-via-functions-of-rapid-decay) asking questions about an alternative equivalent way to define the Schwartz-Bruhat space via functions of rapid decay. Also, my first question seems to be related to  [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131993/bruhat-schwartz-functions-and-derivatives-in-p-adic-numbers/132012#132012).

Answer (score 11):

I strongly recommend you to read the [François Bruhat paper](http://www.scopus.com/record/display.url?eid=2-s2.0-0010038364&origin=inward&txGid=B29C264983E9AB0C088E3340DE92B7F7.fM4vPBipdL1BpirDq5Cw:2), that Osborne cites. For an arbitrary locally compact (not necessarily abelian) group $G$ Bruhat defines smooth function $\varphi:G\to{\mathbb C}$ as the one that can be *locally* represented as a composition 
$$
\varphi=\psi\circ\pi
$$
where $\pi:G\to H$ is a continuous homomorphism into a Lie group $H$, and $\psi:H\to{\mathbb C}$ is a "usual" smooth function on $H$ (considered as a smooth manifold). (Actually, this is the definition for the so-called LP-groups, and the general definition becomes obvious after that.)

Bruhat describes the most important properties of the space ${\mathcal E}(G)$ of smooth functions on $G$ (it is not obvious, for example, that ${\mathcal E}(G)$ is always dense in ${\mathcal C}(G)$). As far as I remember, he gives also a definition of a differential operator on $G$, but I am not sure, anyway you can also take a look at [my paper](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=1&option_lang=eng), where differential operators on $G$ are defined as linear maps 
$$
D:{\mathcal E}(G)\to {\mathcal E}(G)
$$
which preserve the support of functions:
$$
\text{supp}(D\varphi)\subseteq \text{supp}\ \varphi,\qquad \varphi\in {\mathcal E}(G).
$$ 
($\text{supp}\ \varphi$ is the set of points in $G$ where the germ of $\varphi$ is non-zero). One can prove (see again [my paper](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=1&option_lang=eng)) that every such operator has unique decomposition
$$
D=\sum_{\alpha\in{\mathbb N}_I}\xi_\alpha\cdot\partial e_\alpha,
$$
where $I$ is the set of indices (in general, infinite) for a given basis $\{e_i;\ i\in I\}$ in the tangent space $T_1(G)$ (=Lie algebra of $G$), ${\mathbb N}_I$ the set of multi-indices over $I$, $\partial e_\alpha$ are the corresponding translation-invariant differential operators on $G$, and $\xi_\alpha$ are some smooth functions on $G$ (defined by $D$).

$D$ is called a *polynomial differential operator*, if  the coefficients $\xi_\alpha$ are polynomials, i.e. usual polynomials of finite sets of real characters $\chi:G\to{\mathbb R}$ (see [Hewitt-Ross](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387941908); obviously, each polynomial on ${\mathbb R}^a\times {\mathbb T}^b\times {\mathbb Z}^c \times F$ vanishes on ${\mathbb T}^b$ and $F$).

Using these notions one can define the Schwartz-Bruhat space ${\mathcal S}(H)$ on an abelian Lie group $H$ as consisting of smooth functions $\psi:H\to{\mathbb C}$ with compactly generated support and with the property
$$
\sup_{x\in H}|D\psi(x)|<\infty,
$$
for every polynomial differential operator $D$ on $H$. And if $G$ is an arbitrary locally compact abelian group (not necessarily a Lie group) then the space ${\mathcal S}(G)$ is defined as the direct limit (=union) of the spaces ${\mathcal S}(H)$ where $H$ runs through all Lie quotient groups of $G$:
$$
{\mathcal S}(G)=\bigcup_H {\mathcal S}(H).
$$
I believe this is equivalent to Osborne's definitions. By $K^m$ he means, I think, the $m$-th power of a set $K\subseteq G$, defined by induction
$$
K^1=K,\qquad K^{m+1}=K^m\cdot K,
$$
where $A\cdot B=\{a\cdot b;\ a\in A,\ b\in B\}$ (this is for your [new post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153856/characterizing-the-schwartz-bruhat-space-via-functions-of-rapid-decay)).

Comment: +1 Thanks! This seems quite useful. I am reading your post slowly later and giving you more feedback. Also, I am trying to read Bruhat's paper, but I struggle with the French (I can only read some of it because I speak Spanish)... the paper has sadly not been translated, right?

Comment: As far as I know, it was not translated. I can send you my papers in English on this topic.

Comment: I would be grateful. Perhaps you could simply add the links to your answer.